# Redirect multiple domains to https only

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

I have three domains:

1. `example.com`
2. `example.net`
3. `domain2.example`

I want all domains (www/non-www/HTTPS/non-HTTPS traffic) to redirect to `https://www.example.com`.

I know I need to redirect `example.net` and `domain2.example` (www/non-www and HTTPS) first to `example.com` and then `https://www.example.com`  (SSL certificate is only for `example.com` and `www.example.com`).

`.htaccess` (whole file):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond !{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond !{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.net [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2.example [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain1\.com" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond !{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond !{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.net [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2.example [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com" [R=301,L]

# disable directory listing
Options -Indexes

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Only `example.com` redirect rules seems to be working rigth, but `example.net` and `domain2.example` redirects does not work. Is this possible to get work?

Comment: 1) "first to example.com and then https://www.example.com" you do not need two chained redirections, I would even advise againts and 2) you do not need to escape characters in the redirection URL, it is not a regex, so `/` and `.` are fine as is. 3) In general for redirections I recomnmend doing them in Apache main configuration and not in `.htaccess` as this will solve many problems and you can use `Redirect` directives that will be far enough for simpler redirection needs as these.

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough:

```
RewriteCond !{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Keep in mind that in order to respond to `https://` requests for other domains, you need to have the certificate for that domain name (you need it even if you only want to do the redirect!).

Comment: So it's not possible transfer domain without certificate to correct one without warning?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you think about it, it makes sense, why would my browser trust your redirect if you don't have the certificate.

Comment: And you will have separate certs for all the domains you're forwarding to that hosting?

Comment: Either separate certs, or one cert with multiple domain names ([Subject Alternative Names](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-ssl-san/))